# Type annotation for nested trait type?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a top-level trait(Actor) that needs a generic type.
The generic type is an enum(Message) that accepts a type with generic trait.
How do I infer the low-level trait on the constructor function??

To clarify my problem, I have made an [example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=222c8020135d465c9b7346dc898c0b51) to reproduce the error explained above.
How can i resolve the compile error?

```rust
// main.rs

pub struct ProducerManager {
  actor_ch: String,
}

pub trait Actor <T> 
{
  fn new()-> Self;

  fn send(&self, msg:T) -> Result<(),()>;
}

impl <P> Actor< Message<P> > for ProducerManager
where
  P: Price
{
  fn new()-> Self {
      Self{actor_ch:"".to_string()}
  }

  fn send(&self, msg: Message<P>) -> Result<(),()> {
    println!("{:?}", msg);
    Ok(())
  }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct OrderMsg<P> 
where
  P: Price
{
  order_id: u32,
  order_price: P,
  amount: u32,
}

#[derive(std::fmt::Debug)]
pub enum Message<P>
where
  P: Price
{
  NewOrder(OrderMsg<P>),
  Exit
}


pub trait Price: std::fmt::Debug {
  /* some legacy traits.. */
}


fn main(){
  let pm:ProducerManager = ProducerManager::new();
  // ...

}
```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80e3dc6f4e1e5f954828ad5d0813ceea ?

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur for the comment.
Is there alternative solution while keeping <T> generic on `Actor` trait,
instead of bounding `fn send(){}` with `T`?
---
My actual implementation of `Actor` is a lot complexed that the example.
(It has more generics other than T and related to more functions one another)

Comment: well yes you could remove new from this trait or use associate type instead of a generic, there is multiple way but all your code look very obscure. I did the best solution based on what you provided I can't guess the rest.

Comment: Then https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a29d4729d3ad837a4317726ca2e81a0?